# Copy items from ListBox to CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox, checkedlistbox

There are many questions that ask the opposite of this question, unfortunately none of them have worked for me. I have the following code to achieve my purpose:

```
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

The problem is that when I do this, I don't get the values inside the `ListBox`, rather the `System.Data.DataRowView` items. So my `CheckedListBox` gets populated with exactly this, `System.Data.DataRowView` strings, which are all the same and don't show the actual string value.

**Edit**: I bind to the `ListView` this way: I have a `DataTable ds`, and:

```
listBox1.DataSource = ds;
```

Comment: so how do you bind to `listbox`?

Comment: Did you set the DisplayMember property for the CheckedListBox to the same value used for the Listbox?

Comment: what is in the `ds`? What are the Display and Value  members of the `listbox`?

Comment: @Steve The DisplayMember property for the ListBox is set to none. I don't see the Checkedlistbox having that property.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9dzztb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Steve Unfortunately I'm not targeting .NEt 4.5 or 4.6 it seems. I don't have a diplaymember property on my checkedlistobx.

Comment: This property exists from NET 1.1

Comment: The property `DisplayMember` exists in all framework versions, but for some reason is hidden from both designer and intellisense.

Comment: Yes, is hidden frome me as well.

Comment: Found this that seems to confirm the missing intellisense tooltip but not the existence of the property https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/25f6683f-4b18-4aaa-b445-c53096e53715/checklistboxdisplaymember-missing-from-intellisense-and-properties?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (var dataRowView in listBox1.Items.OfType<DataRowView>())
{
     checkedListBox1.Items.Add(dataRowView[0].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For some unknown reason, `DataSource`, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties are hidden for `CheckedListBox` control.

If you want to copy the the list box items text, the correct way is to use [ListControl.GetItemText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext(v=vs.110).aspx) method like this

```
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(listBox1.GetItemText(item));
```

But this way it will be hard to find which source **object** is checked (for instance when enumerating [CheckedItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx)). A better way would be to define your own class like this

```
class MyListItem
{
    public object Value;
    public string Text;
    public override string ToString() { return Text; }
}
```

and use

```
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(new MyListItem { Value = item, Text = listBox1.GetItemText(item) });
```

Comment: Thank you. When you say "which source object is selected", you mean from listBox1? I intend in the near future to add an event so that whenever user clicks on a checkedlistbox item, it also gets selected on the listBox, and then other functionality happens.

Comment: Yes. In fact from list box data source. And by selected I mean checked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a cast like the following :

```
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
 {
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add((ListItem)item);   
 }
```

or else you can use like this:

```
foreach (ListItem item in listBox1.Items)
 {
     checkedListBox1.Items.Add(item);   
 }
```

even this also may help you(use like this if you want text and value);

```
for(int i=0;i<listBox1.Items.Count-1;i++)
   {
      checkedListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = listBox1.Items[i].Text, Value = listBox1.Items[i].Text });   
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately I am only targeting .NET 3.5, so I don't have access to ListItem class.

Comment: This is tagged `WinForms`

Answer (score 1):

The text displayed by [derived ListControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) classes like a CheckedListBox, when these controls are binded to a datasource, is ruled by the property [DisplayMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9dzztb(v=vs.110).aspx). This property equals to a string representing the name of a property (or a columnname) in the datasource.

So before adding the new items to your checkedlistbox I suggest to write

```
checkedListBox1.DataSource = listBox1.DataSource       
checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = listBox1.DisplayMember
checkedListBox1.ValueMember = listBox1.ValueMember
```

And no need to create a loop reading all the items from the source listbox, just use the same datasource and your are ready

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work for me, I still get the same strings: "System.Data.DataRowView"

Comment: @Iason but the Listbox works correctly? If yes then the ds variable that you use to set the DataSource of the listbox is not a DataView, probably a DataSet? Has this DataSet more than one Table? If yes then there is also the property DataMember that disambiguate what table to use to display the content of the listbox. You should set this also jn the CheckedListBox

Comment: Yes, listbox works correctly. ds is a datatable, like I said on my original question. I should have used dt to avoid confusion.

Comment: I can't imagine what is failing in this example. Other answers here allows you to reach your goal albeit I have the feeling that something is at work here